How to properly read over TCP when size is not known?
I've always used "over TCP" protocols with a fixed and known size. But what about reading data without a known size where the 'end' is marked by a delimiter? (e.g HTTP Headers) This is the function I normally use:
int TcpClient::Recv(std::vector<unsigned char>& buf, size_t toRecv){

    int total = 0;
    do{
        int nRecv = SSL_read(ssl, buf.data() + total, toRecv - total);
        if(nRecv <= 0)
            break;
        total += nRecv;

    }while (total < toRecv);
    
    return total;
}

The underlying layer is blocking. Again, this would work fine for  known size messages. An option would be reading one byte at a time until the delimiter is found but that would be extremely inefficient due to the overhead of such many function calls. Is it possible to achieve such thing without non-blocking or without the use of hard coded timeouts? Thanks.

You read the stream of data, usually in fixed-size chunks, and look for the delimiter. You have to be prepared to parse the data after the delimiter as part of the next message. Be careful to handle the case where the delimiter itself is split between chunks (you mention HTTP headers - those use the pair \r\n as a delimiter, and it could just fall on the boundary between two chunks).

Yeah but with this current function, let's say I read 1k at a time, if the response is smaller than that, it will block, waiting for more data to come until that 1k is filled. And reducing the chunk size only implies having more function calls.

That's how it's usually done. You read 1K of data, and then you figure out which part of it is headers and which part is body. You'd need the body eventually anyway, so it doesn't really matter at which point you wait for it to arrive.

I do understand that HTTP responses are usually above 1k of data but, with this given code, if the response was less than 1k of data, and the other peer does not close the connection, SSL_read will just block waiting for more data to come. Something like a timeout must be used in that case I think.

SSL_read can do a short read: "If num is higher than the number of bytes buffered then the read functions will return with the bytes buffered. If no more bytes are in the buffer, the read functions will trigger the processing of the next record. Only when the record has been received and processed completely will the read functions return reporting success. At most the contents of one record will be returned." Presumably, if your server produces less than 1K of data, it wouldn't leave the record open and incomplete.

Blocking networking functions in general only block whilst waiting for the first byte to arrive, once they've read something they return immediately. Your code should just work, have you tried it and encountered problems?

@Jozese: "... I read 1k at a time, if the response is smaller than that, it will block, waiting for more data to come until that 1k is filled" - that's not how recv or read work, they will only block if no data are available but otherwise can return immediately with fewer data than requested. SSL_read also does this short read but with a catch: it will block until at least one full SSL frame could be read since without getting the full frame it could not decrypt the data.

@AlanBirtles Problem was within the loop. Reading up to 1k bytes just with one SSL_read call does work as intended. Reading 1024 bytes until delimiter is found works now since SSL_read does indeed short reading.

@SteffenUllrich Exactly, it was blocking since there was not any more data to read and connection was not closed by the peer since i was using HTTP/1.1 with Keep-alive connection header. It's all good now :)
